# how do i setup tensorboard profiler for training , as currently is not working and not showing profiling tab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, databricks, tensorboard

I have wanted to add profiling to my train code , but its not showing up in tensorboard

```
%load_ext tensorboard
experiment_log_dir = '/dbfs/prajwal.rao/logs/'
tboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = "/dbfs/prajwal.rao/logs/mle_lstm_combined_profile",
                                                 histogram_freq = 1,
                                                 profile_batch = '500,540')

model.fit(train_dataset_val, 
                     steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                     epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                     validation_data=val_dataset_val,
                     validation_steps=validation_steps,
                     verbose=2,callbacks = [tboard_callback])
```

I have installed tensorboard-plugin-profile on my system but cant see the profile section:

[image]

but in the logs the data is there eg:
/dbfs/prajwal.rao/logs/mle_lstm_combined_profile/train/plugins/profile/2022_01_19_01_55_20/1221-040809-hr2wu5va-10-173-52-147.input_pipeline.pb0